# Jquery is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is (html + php) code.

```
<li class='has-sub cuisines'><a href='javascript:void(0)'><span>Cuisine</span></a>
        <ul>
      <li class=""><a href='javascript:void(0)'><span><input type="text" name="search_cuisine" id="search_cuisine" placeholder=" Search Cuisine Here" /></span></a></li>
       <!--<img id="loader_cuisine" src="images/preloader_8.gif"/>-->
               <div id="list_cuisine" >
              <?php
              $row_count=0;
            $query="select cuisine_ID,cuisine_name from cuisine_master where del_flag=1 and display_flag=1 order by cuisine_name";
            $r= mysql_query($query);
            while($result=  mysql_fetch_array($r))
            {

                $ii=0;
                $query12="select distinct r.res_ID from restaurant_master r, buffet_master b, restaurant_cuisine_master cm where r.del_flag=1 and r.res_status=1 and b.res_ID=r.res_ID and cm.res_ID=r.res_ID and cm.cuisine_ID=$result[cuisine_ID]";
                $r12= mysql_query($query12);
                    while($result12=  mysql_fetch_array($r12))
                    {

                               $ii++;

                    }
                if($row_count<10 && $ii>0)
                {
                    $row_count++;

               ?>
            <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'><span><input type="checkbox" name="cuisine[]" id="cuisine_<?php echo $result['cuisine_ID']; ?>" class="cuisine" value="<?php echo $result['cuisine_ID']; ?>"/><label for="cuisine_<?php echo $result['cuisine_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $result['cuisine_name']; ?>(<?php echo $ii; ?>)</label></span></a></li>
               <?php
                }

            }
            ?>
               </div>
       </ul>    
       </li>
```

This is Jquery Code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cuisines').click(function(e){
        $('#additional,#seating,#budget,#locations,#last_order,#discount,#buffet_type').removeClass('active');
        $('.cuisines').addClass('active');
        $('.cuisines ul').slideDown('normal');
        $('#locations ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#additional ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#seating ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#budget ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#last_order ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#discount ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#buffet_type ul').slideUp('normal');

    });

});
```

this is the updated javascript code but cuisines li is not closed after opened.
When I clicked on cuisines li then it is open all ul elements but when i clicked on its ul element then also open and close all ul elements this should not be done because ids and classes of li and ul element are different.

Comment: Create a JSFiddle with your rendered HTML and javascript so it can be viewed without any PHP code.

Comment: You are missing the context of the selector.

Comment: how is this. Your `<div id="list_cuisine" >` is not inside `li`. I think your HTML structure is wrong. Please correct it

Comment: jQuery is working fine, you're using it wrong.

Comment: how to detect that cuisine ul is opened and when it is opened then how it will be closed in jquery

Comment: Can u create a Fiddle for it? it would be easier to see things working! :)

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. I'm guessing it's a selectform for cuisines, that is supposed to show a top 10 of matching restaurants. But what about the sliding stuff? Where are those elements? Also, adding code comments and proper indentation is really not that hard...

Comment: Use an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) while learning HTML. It will let you know about errors and such that you should fix. When that is done, open your developer console and look at the DOM tree, and compare and contrast it before and after clicking on the `.cousines` element. Finally, get your hands on a [good tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/) and use some time reading it. Just forging ahead is good, but at some point you need to actually understand what you are doing.

Comment: The way the question stands I would vote to close, but as it has an open bounty I cannot. Please rewrite the question so that it is more clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 12):

This code should have to be written like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $('.cuisines').click(function(){ // click the cuisines li
        i++;
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active'); // add an active class to clicked li and remove from other siblings li
        $('ul', this).slideDown('normal'); // slidedown the ul of clicked li only
        $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp('normal'); // slideup all the siblings ul which are in view.

        if(i%2===0){
           $('ul', this).slideUp('normal'); // slideup the child ul of clicked li
           $(this).removeClass('active'); // remove the active class from current active li.cuisines
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 9):

The solution is actually really simple and requires only two small changes in your code.

**SOLUTION**

1. The jQuery function `slideToggle` will automatically do what you need.

Simply change the line from:

```
$('.cuisines ul').slideDown('normal');
```

to

```
 $('.cuisines ul').slideToggle('normal');
```

2. Change the click handler selector to be very specific to only the top link:

HTML:

```
<li class='has-sub cuisines'>
  <a href='javascript:void(0)'>
   <span class="toggler">Cuisine</span>
  </a>
   ...
</li>`
```

JS:

```
  $('li.cuisines span.toggler').click(function(e){
    ...
```

Here is a link to the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/56sdLxht/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Try adding stopPropagation function.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $('.cuisines').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();

        i++;
        //alert("hello : "+$(".cuisines ul").val());
        $('#additional,#seating,#budget,#locations,#last_order,#discount,#buffet_type').removeClass('active');
        $('.cuisines').addClass('active');
        $('.cuisines ul').slideDown('normal');
        $('#locations ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#additional ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#seating ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#budget ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#last_order ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#discount ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('#buffet_type ul').slideUp('normal');

        if(i%2===0){
        $('.cuisines ul').slideUp('normal');
        $('.cuisines').removeClass('active');
        }
    });

});    

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Html

Cuisine

```
<div class="menu-toggle hidden" id="customize-menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="">
      <a href='javascript:void(0)'>
      <span>
      <input type="text" name="search_cuisine" id="search_cuisine" placeholder=" Search Cuisine Here" />
      </span>
      </a>
      </li>
       <!--<img id="loader_cuisine" src="images/preloader_8.gif"/>-->
        <div id="list_cuisine" >
        <li>
        <a href='javascript:void(0)'>
        <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cuisine[]" id="cuisine_<?php echo $result['cuisine_ID']; ?>" class="cuisine" value="<?php echo $result['cuisine_ID']; ?>"/>
        <label for="cuisine_<?php echo $result['cuisine_ID']; ?>"></label>
        </span>
        </a>
        </li>
        </div>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

### Script

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cuisines').click(function(e){       
      $(".menu-toggle:not(#customize-menu)").hide();
     $("#customize-menu").toggle();
 });
     $('.cuisines input,ul,li').click(function(e){       
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
});
</script>
```

### Js Fiddle Link [solved solution here]

[https://jsfiddle.net/dybwbs92/5/embedded/result/](https://jsfiddle.net/dybwbs92/4/)